# Can't make POST request because of the CORS problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, cors

Disclaimer: I know this question has been posted a lot of times but even after looking at other topics I still cant figure this out.

I am trying to make a post request to an API using JQuery, with the ajax method, but the browser keeps blocking it due to the Cross Origin policy. I do not own this API and thus I cannot change its code.
I have tried multiple solutions, including adding "forbidden headers" to the request.

jQuery code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://vcdn2.space/api/source/" + substring,
    data: payload,
    headers: {
        'origin': 'https://vcdn2.space',
        'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
        'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
        'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
        'referer': "https://vcdn2.space/v/" + substring
    },
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        alert("ok1");
    },
    failure: function (response) {
        alert("ok2");
    }
```

I can make this request without any problems on the server side (using Python, Django), but in this case, it needs to be done on the client side. Any ideas?

Comment: You cannot do it. CORS is basic web security. You'll have to use your own proxy server.

Comment: You can't from only browser-side javascript.

Comment: @James Is there any way I can send a request on the server side with the ip of the client, without using a vpn?

Comment: `with the ip of the client` no, because then the CDN would not be able to send a response to your web server.

Comment: @James This is kind of problematic for me ngl. Is there any way I can put an iframe on my html code and "listen" for requests the client does to that iframe? Or somehow scrape the contents of the iframe using the client side javascript?

Comment: Nope.  You need to either do the entire session with the CDN from your server code, or have the CDN allow your website to do CORS requests.